# When do we overwrite the default RBS settings?

Tags: rbs

According to default values, BLOB files should be cleared after 30 days , if they are not referenced to any Content Database record.

So, My question is when do we really need to overwrite the default RBS settings(with respect to SharePoint 2010)? I hope, the default settings may suit for whom consider the database backup(data, log) without RBS contents.

Is there any other reason behind this to keep the default RBS garbage collection period?

Comment: Closing this as not constructive, we can only speculate as to why this is the case. This speculation will not result in useful or definitive answers on the question and such is not a good fit for the site.

Comment: If you can rephrase this so it is constructive, flag it after editing and we'll reopen.